# Using menus anywhere on page - how to stop them expanding by default when not used in menu region ( e.g. in a block or panel)?

Tags: 7, routes, blocks, panels, navigation

I am trying this with superfish but the menu options are expanded by default.

What would I need to do to get it to behave like it does in a menu (i.e. collapsed by default).

I want to use the menu drop down within the content (**Edit** i.e. within a panel or a block so that I can have drop-down menu functionality anywhere on the page (hence the tags).

Comment: some time back I did opposite of this, I had to chaneg menu items expanded by default.What I did was implementing hook_menu_link_alter()

function hook_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  $item['expanded'] = 1;
}
you can check if it works for you was well with some condition check for menu type and using $item['expanded'] = 0;

Comment: +1 @arpitr thank you - that's encouraging! I'll take a look and report back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I chose in the end was to hand-code a drop down, based on the HTML markup output by a Views Exposed Filter form that I am already using (this also means that the look and feel is consistent).

So I created a block in the usual way and added the code shown below, and then in my 2-column minipanel added this block to the 2nd column and then added my minipanel to the panel page. The other column, 1st, of the columns contains the views exposed filter as discussed. See screenshots below, after the code:

```
<form>
<select name="field_type_value" class="form-select" onChange="document.location = this.value" value="GO">
<option value=""  selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Add something to our map!</option>
<option value="node/add/local-resource">person</option>
<option value="node/add/local-resource">organisation</option>
<option value="node/add/local-resource">project</option>
<option value="node/add/local-resource">wifi hotspot</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Other features in the code above:

- Dropdown Form, when click on element, go to link without hitting a submit button - credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347080/dropdown-form-when-click-on-element-go-to-link-without-hitting-a-submit-button
- Call-to-action "Add something to our map!" is not a selectable item in itself, so made this unselectable - credit: http://www.lattimore.id.au/2005/06/18/disable-options-in-a-select-dropdown-element/

Remaining thing to do:

- The URLs each to call a different add content type form for each of the subtypes of content - I'll need to work out how to select a certain template from a URL or otherwise, but will be basing my customised content type form off this answer: [How do you theme a content type's create/edit form in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/how-do-you-theme-a-content-types-create-edit-form-in-drupal-7)

[image: widget not clicked on 1 of 2]
[image: widget clicked on showing dropped down]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module. It allows you to create a block that displays a menu, and it comes with a bunch of settings to control how the menu is displayed.

Comment: I have looked at this but it didn't do what I needed - as per my question. *Or at least, I* couldn't get to do that. I will re-visit it and try again but have tried several times already. But actually, it's not completely clear to me from the module description that is it going to do what I want: "So… have you ever used the Main and Secondary menu links feature on your theme and wondered “how the hell do I display any menu items deeper than that?” etc. Nothing about collapsing menu options - which is what I need to do, *anywhere* on the page.