# themed node add form cannot render form properly

Tags: nodes, forms, theming

I would like to theme a node add form with the id of "project-node-form". I followed the steps I found online too add the hook theme code in the template.php under the theme and there seem to be nothing wrong with the code. Unfortunately the page template is rendered without the forms in it, is there anyway I can resolve this?

The name of my theme is 'test' and the template file is 'page--node--add--project'

the line  **print drupal_render($form);** has been included in the page--node--add--project.tpl.php

```
<?php
function test_theme() {
return array( 'project-node-form' => array(
'render element' => 'form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'test') . '/templates',
'template' => 'page--node--add--project',
),
);
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you look here? https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122

Comment: You can find possible answers here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/how-do-you-theme-a-content-types-create-edit-form-in-drupal-7